# wordpress crop thumbnail

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I need to crop wordpress thumbnail like in the image below, i.e., crop piece of image from left top corner, without scaling of image.

[image: example]

Can I do this without plugins?

Comment: Yes, you can do this without plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you'd crop to the top-left of a much larger `<img>` using a parent container.

```css
.crop {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="crop">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/pRSJBDI.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: no, this is bad idea. the target audience of my site have bad internet-connection (3G), and I should economy traffic

Comment: @nick You can manually crop images in the Media Uploader: https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/crop-image-wordpress/